How to align label to the right in a vertical MUI Slider in ReactJS?
I am using ReactJS/TS with MUI (Material-UI), and I need to implement a vertical slider where the label turns to the right. By default, in MUI, the label is on the left when using a vertical slider. I've gone through the API documentation but couldn't find a way to adjust the label to appear on the right instead of the left.
I tried using a custom label, but it utilizes the tooltip component, which doesn't look good when dragged extensively. The tooltip causes the label to flicker because it is re-rendering frequently.
Here is an image of the current slider setup:

How can I adjust the label to be on the right side without the flickering issue?
code sand box
https://25k7jg.csb.app/
code :
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";

const minDistance = 1;
export default function App() {
  const [value1, setValue1] = React.useState<number[]>([20, 37]);
  const handleChange1 = (
    event: Event,
    newValue: number | number[],
    activeThumb: number
  ) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(newValue)) {
      return;
    }

    if (activeThumb === 0) {
      setValue1([Math.min(newValue[0], value1[1] - minDistance), value1[1]]);
    } else {
      setValue1([value1[0], Math.max(newValue[1], value1[0] + minDistance)]);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ paddingTop: "20px", height: "500px" }} className="App">
      <Slider
        orientation="vertical"
        value={value1}
        step={0.1}
        onChange={handleChange1}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        disableSwap
      />
    </div>
  );
}



Thanks for your help!

You can manage it by setting the left and top CSS properties for the  MuiSlider-valueLabel  class manually. I created this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nxzqnv-qp3hcd?file=demo.tsx,index.css for you to test/review it easily. Is that what you need right?

It is very good thank you a lot! @OnurDoğan , but how would you change the tooltip arrow to direct as if it came out of the slider bullet? In your example it direct down instead of the direction of the Bullet

You're welcome, it's default was like this so I didn't update it but if we would like to update it, need to update MuiSlider-valueLabel::before. Its default was left: 50%, bottom: 0%. I changed it to bottom: 50%, left: 0 and it brought the arrow left. You can review it from the same link, I just updated it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nxzqnv-qp3hcd?file=demo.tsx,index.css. It is probably bottom: 50%, left: 100% in your case

do you know how to remove the flickering? for step={0.1}, I tried with    font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums; but didn't worked

@OnurDoğan hey do you know how to solve the flickering for step={0.1}? I tried with font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums; without luck

I just updated the same link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nxzqnv-qp3hcd?file=demo.tsx,index.css, is that what you need?

ok chat gpt said to add ```valueLabelFormat={value => value.toFixed(1)} // Always show one decimal place
?

and add an answer dor future people

You're welcome @dolev-dublon, good to be helpful. Sure, it's a good question and also has answers for some other connected things. It might be helpful for someone else too, so I added some links to explain the fixes

For managing the label's position, we can override the left and top CSS properties for the MuiSlider-valueLabel class something like (It would be better to configure it by using MUI styles):
.MuiSlider-valueLabel {
  left: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

On the other hand, if you would like to change the tooltip arrow icon's style, need to override some properties of the MuiSlider-valueLabel::before

For example, its default CSS properties were left: 50%, bottom: 0 in my case and it was displayed on the bottom aligned. If we would like to display it on the left side aligned, need to change CSS styles like (It would be better to configure it by using MUI styles):
.MuiSlider-valueLabel::before {
  bottom: 50%; 
  left: 0;
}

I also created a DEMO LINK to review and test it easily
Hope, it's clear and helpful

hey onur do you know how to solve the issue of the z index?

I added an image in the question

You might add z-index: 2 for the MuiSlider-valueLabel and z-index: 1 for the table component's label, it might work but not sure. Need to see the code of the components in the image. I think you may create a new question for that
